# Memory footprint of VAOs

Tags: opengl-es

Can someone tell me how large VAOs are in cpu/gpu memory compared to VBOs? My plan was to allocate a large number of VAOs at program start as a pool, then assign them to certain render calls as needed.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

VAOs are just meta-data - buffer bindings and offsets. VBOs are actual data buffers containing all of your vertex data. VAOs will be orders of magnitude smaller than VBOs.

That said, why do you want to create a pool of them? That implies you'll be recreating them at draw time, which somewhat defeats the point. The only real advantage of VAOs vs just direct binds and offsets is that you don't have the runtime cost of recreating them all the time ...

Comment: I have a pool of initialized VAOs. When an object doesn't need a vao anymore, it is returned to the pool but not deinitialized. If anothe object needs a vao it just takes one from the pool, changes the attribute bindings and uses it.